# TQFP Atmega328pu-th cant upload sketch sync error (breadboard)

Tags: arduino-uno-smd

So I have a USB to ftdi connected to my qtfp 32 socket trying to upload a sketch but I get a sync error , as far as I am aware I have uploaded the sketch correctly

Comment: sync error usually means upload was impossible. In your case, wiring is the first problem candidate, sorry.

Comment: Does your chip have a bootloader on it? How have you wired up your setup?

Comment: @majenko exactly like this picture Burn https://imgur.com/gallery/8xpHGqo

Comment: Which one? The first or second?

Comment: @Majenko sorry if I am using this wrong really new here. the second one with the red board (ftdi) I have everything wired like that but I get sync error. Also my chip has a weird suffix, -UTH

Comment: And did you first wire up like the first way and install the bootloader?

Comment: yep and it said boot loader burned successfully or something like that, I've checked everything so many times no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Check the crystal. Make sure it's as close to the chip as possible. If you are using a breadboard, try lower value capacitors, or no capacitors.

Comment: @gerben thank you will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys I managed to figure it out I had to remove the dtr pin from pin 29 , I made a video to help anyone else looking to do it, I don't know if it breeches any self promotion? But hope it helps because i found it difficult to find any resources. https://youtu.be/5CPYz6Kde7M